# How to make radio button before the text in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to use

```
<label class="radio inline control-label pull-right">
              <input type="radio" value="test">test
</label>
```

but it comes after the text

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove margin left from radio input. You need to add custom style for set margin. You can use following.

```
<label class="radio-inline">
      Option 1<input type="radio" name="optradio" style="margin-left: 5px;" >
    </label>
```